# Aplicação Android Incompatível com Tablet (Informação PlayStore)

Tags: android, app, layout, google-play

Desenvolvi recentemente uma app que publiquei na google play store com todos os requisitos necessários, no entanto ao tentar efetuar o download num tablet Asus Zenpad 3S 10 Z500M este surge como incompatível e não permite efetuar o download.

Andei a ver a lista de equipamentos compatíveis com a  minha app que a google play store divulga e dezenas de tablet's são compatíveis...

Porque será que este modelo em específico não é compatível? A versão android é compatível 6.0.1, será pela resolução do ecrã? 9.7'' 1536 x 2048 pixels (~264 ppi pixel density), no entanto eu criei para todas as Views os layout-normal, layout-large e layout-xtra-large.

Aqui está o manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.nuno.bombeiros.bombeirospt">

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
        To resolve problems of firebase in old Versions 4.0.1 at 4.4
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        -->


        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity.MainActivity" />

        <!--
             First Activity to Open
             SplashScreen
        -->
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Pre_Hospitalar.Pre_Hospitalar" />
        <activity android:name=".User_Config.User_Config" />
        <activity android:name=".Pre_Hospitalar.Calculadora_Coma_Glasgow" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Urbanos.CalculadoraAutonomiaARICA" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Urbanos.IncendiosUrbanos" />
        <activity android:name=".Noticias.UI.Feed.RssFeedActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Noticias.UI.Article.ArticleActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Materias_Perigosas.MateriasPerigosasActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Materias_Perigosas.DatabaseHandler.ONU_UI.OnuResultActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Materias_Perigosas.DatabaseHandler.NAME_UI.NomeResultActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Materias_Perigosas.DatabaseHandler.Error_UI.ErrorMessageMateriasPerigosas" />
        <activity android:name=".Corpos_de_Bombeiros.CorposBombeirosActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Corpos_de_Bombeiros.DetailCB.CorposBombeirosDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.IncendiosFlorestaisActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.PontosAgua.PontosAguaActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.PontosAgua.ListaConcelhoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.PontosAgua.ListaActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.PontosAgua.Error_UI.ErrorMessagePontosAguaActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.PontosAgua.DetailActivity.PontosAguaDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.FDI.FDIActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.FDI.FDI_Baixo.FDI_BaixoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.FDI.FDI_Moderado.FDI_ModeradoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.FDI.FDI_Alto.FDI_AltoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.FDI.FDI_Muito_Alto.FDI_Muito_AltoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Florestais.FDI.FDI_Extremo.FDI_ExtremoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Creditos.CreditosActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Incendios_Urbanos.GlossarioIncendiosUrbanosActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Materias_Perigosas.Materias_PerigosasMenuActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Materias_Perigosas.Pictograma.PictogramaDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Materias_Perigosas.Pictograma.PictogramaActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Alguém me poderá ajudar e tentar perceber o que que se possa estar a passar?

Comment: Analisei melhor os dispositivos compatíveis, e penso que o problema da compatibilidade estará no uso da funcionalidade de telefone, neste caso SMS. Existe possibilidade de eu poder usar também em tablet's sem cartão sim? desativando neste caso a funcionalidade? Se sim, como poderei fazer?

Comment: Se eu usar <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" >
</uses-feature> haverá algum problema futuro recorrente? Dentro da app não haverá problema, pois eu tenho a condição que verifica se tem cartão SIM ou não na funcionalidade de envar SMS

Comment: [Algumas permissões](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) relacionadas a hardware implicam que os recursos subjacentes de hardware sejam obrigatórios por padrão. Por isso tem de utilizar `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" >` para que a aplicação possa ser instalada em dispositivos que não sejam telefones.

Answer (score 1):

O Android pode ser executado em diferentes tipos de dispositivos. Ele está presente em telefones, tablets, televisões e até em carros.

O hardware de cada um desses dispositivos têm características diferentes, o que obriga a que as aplicações sejam construídas de forma a tê-las em consideração, caso queiramos que elas corram no maior número de tipos possível.

Para facilitar esse objectivo, o Android fornece um *framework* de desenvolvimento de aplicativos dinâmico que permite ao programador disponibilizar recursos a serem utilizados em função das características do dispositivo, por exemplo diferentes layouts para diferentes dimensões de tela ou diferentes tamanhos de imagens para diferentes densidades de telas.

Por outro lado a aplicação pode ter requisitos de hardware que o dispositivo não pode satisfazer, como por exemplo enviar SMS ou ter um determinado sensor.

É da responsabilidade do programador indicar, no *AndroidManifest.xml*, quais são esses requisitos através 
do elemento `<uses-feature>` e, programaticamente, lidar com facto de eles poderem não estarem disponíveis.

O uso, só por si, de [algumas permissões](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) implicitamente obrigam à existência de requisitos de hardware, tornando a aplicação incompatível com determinados dispositivos.

O Google Play apenas deixa instalar aplicativos compatíveis com o dispositivo.

Essa filtragem é feita baseada nos requisitos [implícitos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#implicit) e nos [explicitamente](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#declared) declarados.

No seu caso, pelo facto de ter a permissão

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

implicitamente requer que o dispositivo seja um telefone. É como tivesse declarado

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" >
```

no *AndroidManifest.xml*.

Para que a sua aplicação possa ser instalada em dispositivos que não sejam telefones tem de explicitamente indicar que tal requisito não é necessário, usando o atributo `android:required`

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" >
```

**Referências:**

- [Device Compatibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html)
- [Elemento `<uses-feature>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)